# Python create list from a list of lists of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, python-2.x

I have a `list` that contains information about ZIP's (their location, size ect) in a list called `enclosures`.

The list is created with this code:

```
for item in g.entries:
    enclosure = [l for l in item["links"] if l["rel"] == "enclosure"]
    if(len(enclosure)>0):
        enclosures.append(enclosure)
```

Every item of the list `enclosures` has the following format:

```
>>> enclosures[0]
[{'type': 'application/zip', 'rel': 'enclosure', 'length': '57648', 'href': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/37748/000003774810000025/0000037748-10-000025-xbrl.zip'}]
```

or another example...

```
>>> enclosures[45]
[{'type': 'application/zip', 'rel': 'enclosure', 'length': '107907', 'href': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1385157/000104746910004400/0001047469-10-004400-xbrl.zip'}]
```

What i need is **to create a list** called `href` which contains every `href` item from the `enclosures list` *in the same order*.

These attempts below have failed.

```
>>> enclosures[46]["href"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#66>", line 1, in <module>
    enclosures[46]["href"]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

>>> enclosures[46][4]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#67>", line 1, in <module>
    enclosures[46][4]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**EDIT**

Dear [timgeb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3620003/timgeb)

I have this result:

```
>>> href = [x['href'] for x in enclosures]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#75>", line 1, in <module>
    href = [x['href'] for x in enclosures]
  File "<pyshell#75>", line 1, in <listcomp>
    href = [x['href'] for x in enclosures]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: The way you do it, `enclosures` is a list of lists of dicts. Is this on purpose? Most of the inner lists, at least those two examples, seem to have just one element. Did you mean `enclosures.extend(enclosure)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
href = [x[0]['href'] for x in enclosures]
```

Comment: @tobias_k ah, i see the problem, give me a second; edit: fixed

Comment: This fixes it, but only if each inner list has exactly one element, which is not apparent from the question.

Comment: @tobias_k ExoticBirdsMerchant said each item has this format, so I think `x[0]` is fine for now.

Comment: thank you so much you have fixed it!!!! Yes all item are exactly identical like those two examples supplied

Comment: Where exactly in the documentation can i read about list of lists of dictionaries? I know list and dictionaries. :P (if any examples plz feel feed to post a link :-) )

Comment: Upvoting in 5 mins due to timer

Comment: @ExoticBirdsMerchant I doubt there's documentation about this, as conceptually there's little difference. You should probably flatten `enclosures` to be a list of dictionaries with `enclosures = [x[0] for x in enclosures]`